# C++: Use auto, or typedef?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'd hate to ask an intentionally subjective question on here, but I don't have anyone else to ask this directly...

I'm trying to "lead by example" in my team by adopting more modern C++ concepts in new code I write. My coworkers are a bit shy of templates, and gripe about having to type `unique_ptr<Foobar>` or `shared_ptr<Foobar>` instead of just `Foobar*` when utilizing some classes I've recently created (factory methods return `unique_ptr`s and I store lists of these objects in vectors using `shared_ptr`).

They twisted my arm and convinced me to typedef these into something easier to type, eg `FoobarUniquePtr`.

But now I'm in a mess of const-correctness with these typedefs. I'd have to define extra typedefs for each const and non const type, and `const const_FoobarUniquePtr` doesn't seem to properly express the const semantics.

So, to my question, would it make sense to stop using these typedefs and instead shove `auto` at my teammates when they complain about having to type the templated smart pointers? I'm also open to other alternatives.

Comment: +1 for attempting to get your co-workers to use more modern practices!

Comment: So is the problem with `unique_ptr<const Foobar>` or `const unique_ptr<Foobar>`?

Comment: sounds like auto was created just for this type of thing.  its a nice shortcut allowing you to just put auto instead of figuring out exactly which type you need to use for the variable.  when you ask whether it makes sense, well, its part of the language standard and using it in this way sounds 'correct' to me.  But of course some personal preference might come into it as I'd imagine some might argue that they'd rather see the explicit type anywhere its used and not rely on auto.  But beyond personal preference, it seems like a valid usage.

Comment: Both of the options you give doesn't require your co-workers to actually learn the good things you're trying to teach them. I'd advocate actually explaining to them **why** this is a bad idea. `auto` is really just a band-aid on this problem, but it's better than the `typedef`s.

Comment: @Useless: Being new to these smart pointers, I naively thought `const FoobarUniquePtr` making the `Foobar` const. Obviously that was wrong. The problem is that I would like to more easily write methods, for example, that return something like `const shared_ptr<const Foobar>&`. Obviously declaring a variable of that type gets long-winded, but `auto` seems to fix this. I've shown auto, and gotten gasps and grumbles that `auto` hides the type information. I'm close to pushing the `auto` concept, but wanted to check with Stackoverflow to see if anyone had an alternative that made more sense.

Comment: How is `FoobarUniquePtr` easier to type than `unique_ptr<Foobar>`? Are you using a keyboard layout without underscores and angle-brackets?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That's called ignorance and unwillingness. That "angle thingy" looks alien to them, they are not used to it. "We won't use that, it is complicated and error prone" ... Nothing rational to find there.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I never said I agreed with them, that's just the feedback I got when they started using my code. To avoid a "the old way works!" revolt, I added the typedefs.

Comment: Thus far, from the comments I'm getting (and thanks, this is exactly the dialog I was hoping to have), I think I'm in the "right" by refactoring out the typedefs and refer them to `auto` for the sake of typing. My methods pretty well self document the return type anyway.

Comment: One note: it is unnecessary to store the objects by `shared_ptr` in vectors if the vector *owns* them. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>` is fine.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I started with a `vector` of `unique_ptr`, but the object lifetime/ownership ended up needing to be shared. The vectors simply provide an easier way to reference other objects within a parent, but the "children" can live on their own.

Comment: @BretKuhns: Okay, just wanted to check that it was not a leftover of the old `auto_ptr` reflexes :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, *auto* makes your life a lot easier.

If you aren't shipping on any esoteric architectures (and have no plans to do so anytime soon), the answer should be "use auto whenever you can".

Comment: This is not always good advice (Although that applies to this comment as well). Sometimes programmer intent may be hidden, or in rare cases something unexpected may happen, and be hard to track down if you're using an evil-compiler-error-message-compiler like GCC or MSVC.

Comment: @rubenvb I agree. Herb Sutter recently declared in his keynote at GoingNative 2012 that we should always be using `auto` except when we want to do type conversions. I'm hoping he's intentionally being sensational. For now, I'm only using auto for things like STL iterators, where no one really cares what the type is and everyone already knows what it will be anyway. If the method name itself conveys the behavior/intent of the type (especially if the return type is part of a template parameter), I could live with someone using `auto`, but I wouldn't default to it.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you need to define all variations you might need.

Get your guys to see the presentaion from Bjarne Stoustrup and read some of the blogs in C++11. As for templates buy some of the books on the book list and "coincedentially" drop some of them on your desk to start the discussion.

You can even write a few powerpoint presentions, and present them to your team members and build up a culture of research.

[Bjarne Stroustrup: C++11 Style](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style)

book list: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Coincidentally, I'm already doing all of this. I just finished watching all of the keynotes from GoingNative 2012, as well as "C++ and Beyond", and a few others I could find online. I recently bought "Modern C++ Design", but that template code probably isn't going to win my coworkers over, at least not until I write some myself and my coworkers catch onto the flexibility.

I've also been making my own presentations on const-correctness, ownership semantics (and move semantics), Lambdas, and then a potpourri presentation of C++11 features.

Answer (score 4):

> I'd have to define extra typedefs for each const and non const type

... which will cause a combinatorial blowup as the number of places where a `const` fits in the type increases. Explain to your colleagues that the amount of work you're doing increases exponentially because they're fighting the language instead of using it. And yes, use `auto` when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

When I create a new class one of the first things I do is:

```
class MyClass
{
public: // Typedefs
    typedef std::shared_ptr<MyClass> Ptr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const MyClass> ConstPtr;
};
```

Then user's of my class can use it like:

```
MyClass::Ptr pMyClass = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

The reason I add them to the class as public typedefs is I hate to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: I had considered that approach. My only issue with your `MyClass::ConstPtr` is that I would read it as if the `ptr` was `const`, not the `MyClass` object. I can't come up with a naming convention that properly conveys what the language easily provides, so I'm leaning toward avoiding the typedefs and just using the language.